# Read File line by line in C mostly with Syscalls

Tags: c

I'm trying to read and parse a file line by line.
I only want to use simple syscalls (`read`, `open`, `close`, ...) and not `fgets` or `getc` because I wish to learn, in a way, fundamentals. (I looked some answers on similar questions but they all use `fgets` and such).

Here's what I have at the moment:a function I wrote that will store 1024 chars in a buffer from a file.

```
int main(void) {
    const char *filename = "file.txt";
    int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof (char) * 1024); 

    read(fd, buffer, 1024);        
    printf("%s", buffer);
    close(fd);
    free(buffer);    
}
```

How does one make a stop at a '\n' for instance?
I know that once I know where to stop, I can use `lseek` with the right offset to continue reading my file where I stopped.

I do not wish to store the whole file in my buffer and then parse it.
I want to add a line in my buffer, then parse that line and realloc my buffer and keep on reading the file.

I was thinking of something like this but I feel like it's badly optimized and not sure where to add the `lseek` afterwards:

```
char *line = malloc(sizeof (char) * 1024);
read(fd, buffer, 1);
int i = 0;
    while(*buffer != '\n' && *buffer != '\0'){
        line[i] = *buffer;
        ++i;
        *buffer++;
        read(fd, buffer, 1); //Assuming i < 1024 and *buffer != NULL
    }


  /* lseek somewhere after, probably should make 2 for loops 
   ** One loop till file isn't completly read
   ** Another loop inside that checks if the end of the line is reached
   ** At the end of second loop lseek to where we left
   */
```

Thanks :)

EDIT: Title for clarifications.

Comment: "How does one make a stop at a '\n' for instance?" Why not `fgets`?.. After all, that's the function is written specifically for the purpose that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your code is unsafe: `read()` doesn't null-terminate the buffer, so you cannot pas it to `printf()` .

Comment: __I only want to use simple syscalls (`read`, `open`, `close`, ...) and not `fgets` or `getc`__

Comment: @JeanHenry I read that part. I'm trying to understand the point of the exercise. If you want to see how `fgets` does it, [read the source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/stdio.subproj/fgets.c) to see what's going on.

Comment: Then you will have to implement your own version of `fgets()`, including fun things like buffering.

Comment: Writting functions with only syscalls to sort of implement my own fgets and learning along the way. This is for learning purposes only. Not work or anything.

Comment: `read`, `open`, `close` are **not** standard C functions.  `fgetc()` is a standard function.  In essence you are not trying to learn how to use C, but how to implement C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to use `read` to read a line at a time (what `fgets` or `getline` are intended to do), you must keep track of the *offset* within the file after you locate each `'\n'`. It is then just a matter of reading a line at a time, beginning the next `read` at the *offset* following the current.

I understand wanting to be able to use the low-level functions as well as `fgets` and `getline`. What you find is that you basically end up re-coding (in a less efficient way) what is already done in `fgets` and `getline`. But it is certainly good learning. Here is a short example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSZ 128

ssize_t readline (char *buf, size_t sz, char *fn, off_t *offset);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) return 1;

    char line[BUFSZ] = {0};
    off_t offset = 0;
    ssize_t len = 0;
    size_t i = 0;

    /* using open/read, read each line in file into 'line' */
    while ((len = readline (line, BUFSZ, argv[1], &offset)) != -1)
        printf (" line[%2zu] : %s (%zd chars)\n", i++, line, len);

    return 0;
}

/* read 'sz' bytes from file 'fn' beginning at file 'offset'
   storing all chars  in 'buf', where 'buf' is terminated at
   the first newline found. On success, returns number of
   characters read, -1 on error or EOF with 0 chars read.
 */
ssize_t readline (char *buf, size_t sz, char *fn, off_t *offset)
{
    int fd = open (fn, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: file open failed '%s'.\n",
                __func__, fn);
        return -1;
    }

    ssize_t nchr = 0;
    ssize_t idx = 0;
    char *p = NULL;

    /* position fd & read line */
    if ((nchr = lseek (fd, *offset, SEEK_SET)) != -1)
        nchr = read (fd, buf, sz);
    close (fd);

    if (nchr == -1) {   /* read error   */
        fprintf (stderr, "%s() error: read failure in '%s'.\n",
                __func__, fn);
        return nchr;
    }

    /* end of file - no chars read
    (not an error, but return -1 )*/
    if (nchr == 0) return -1;

    p = buf;    /* check each chacr */
    while (idx < nchr && *p != '\n') p++, idx++;
    *p = 0;

    if (idx == nchr) {  /* newline not found  */
        *offset += nchr;

        /* check file missing newline at end */
        return nchr < (ssize_t)sz ? nchr : 0;
    }

    *offset += idx + 1;

    return idx;
}
```

**Example Input**

The following datafiles are identical except the second contains a *blank line* between each line of text.

```
$ cat dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.

$ cat dat/captnjack2.txt
This is a tale

Of Captain Jack Sparrow

A Pirate So Brave

On the Seven Seas.
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/readfile dat/captnjack.txt
 line[ 0] : This is a tale (14 chars)
 line[ 1] : Of Captain Jack Sparrow (23 chars)
 line[ 2] : A Pirate So Brave (17 chars)
 line[ 3] : On the Seven Seas. (18 chars)

$ ./bin/readfile dat/captnjack2.txt
 line[ 0] : This is a tale (14 chars)
 line[ 1] :  (0 chars)
 line[ 2] : Of Captain Jack Sparrow (23 chars)
 line[ 3] :  (0 chars)
 line[ 4] : A Pirate So Brave (17 chars)
 line[ 5] :  (0 chars)
 line[ 6] : On the Seven Seas. (18 chars)
```

Comment: What about non-seekable streams?

Comment: You would basically have to buffer the entire file somewhere on one single read and parse the buffer following one read.

Comment: I don't think you have to buffer *the entire file* in that case. But you certainly have to buffer *some* of it.

Comment: Agreed, you have to buffer whatever you can and basically *inch-worm* through the file filling/parsing whatever size buffer you do have. For the example above, if it were non-seekable, you would basically need to move your output from `main()` into `readline()` and print each line as you found each `'\n'`. In that case you would just have to live with the combined read and write in a single function.

Comment: I get the idea. I'll have to re-read few times, write down and think over it but this definetly shows me the right track and the different uses of the syscalls together with buffer usage. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped. If you look at the `getline` function, `readline` above was written to mirror its functionality, just using the low-level `read`. the difference between the higher-level functions and low-level functions is *You* are responsible for keeping track of the read-pointer and testing for all potential EOF/error conditions. It's a great learning exercise. Take your time re-reading, there is a *lot* packed into what on the surface looks like a simple `readline()` function.

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially implementing your own version of [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html). Avoiding character-by-character read of non-seekable streams in `fgets` is enabled by an *internal buffer* associated with `FILE*` data structure.

Internally, `fgets` uses a function to fill that buffer using "raw" input-output routines. After that, `fgets` goes through the buffer character-by-character to determine the location of `'\n'`, if any. Finally, `fgets` copies the content from the internal buffer into the user-supplied buffer, and null-terminates the result if there is enough space.

In order to re-create this logic you would need to define your own `FILE`-like `struct` with a pointer to buffer and a pointer indicating the current location inside the buffer. After that you would need to define your own version of `fopen`, which initializes the buffer and returns it to the caller. You would also need to write your own version of `fclose` to free up the buffer. Once all of this is in place, you can implement your `fgets` by following the logic outlined above.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof (char) * 1024); 
read(fd, buffer, 1024);        
printf("%s", buffer);
```

There are several errors in the above code.

First, `malloc` is not a syscall (and neither is [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) ....). And `sizeof(char)`  is 1 by definition. If you want to *only* use syscalls (listed in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)) you'll need to use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and you should request virtual memory in multiple of the page size (see [getpagesize(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html) or [sysconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html)....), which is often (but not always) 4 kilobytes.
If you can use `malloc` you should code against its failure and you'll better zero the obtained buffer, so at least

```
const int bufsiz = 1024;
char*buffer = malloc(bufsiz);
if (!buffer) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
memset(buffer, 0, bufsiz);
```

Then, and more importantly, [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) is returning a number that you should *always* use (at least against failure):

```
ssize_t rdcnt = read(fd, buffer, bufsiz);
if (rdcnt<0) { perror("read"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

You'll generally increment some pointer (by `rdcnt` bytes)  if the `rdcnt` is positive. A zero count means an end-of-file.

At last your `printf` is using `<stdio.h>` and you might use [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)
instead. If using `printf`, remember that it is buffering. Either end the format with a `\n`, or use [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)

If you use `printf`, be sure to end the string with a zero byte. A possibility might have been to pass `bufsiz-1` to your  `read`; since we zeroed the zone before, we are sure to have a terminating zero byte.

BTW, you could study the source code of some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) implementation of the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) such as [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) or [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)

Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`), to use the debugger (`gdb`), perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) & [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)

Comment: Very true, hadn't formulated my title right with the "syscalls only". Thanks for the additionnal info on safety measures regarding buffers and read.

Comment: Then, you are not allowed to use `malloc`, only `mmap` (or use some `static`  or local buffer).

Comment: I can use other functions that syscalls. "Syscall only" was just a reference to my old title. Anyways, pointless comment... Still thanks for the infos